# KInetic JS scale shapes on mouse move

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Is it possible to create an application using Kinetic.js where you create a shape, then scale it as you move the mouse around? I couldn't find anything in the Kinetic APIs, so I am mixing in "raw" JQuery. In particular, I use `$("canvas").last().mousemove` function, but it turns out this is actually very slow.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/G6NV8/2/) is the JSFiddle.

Any tips on making it faster?

I don't think the Kinetic.js has support for `layer.on("mousemove", fn)`, because it seems to only apply to shapes.

Comment: How about adjusting the position of the drawn shape instead of creating/deleting it on every mouse move

Comment: Yeah... you should just keep a reference to the shape and modify its width/height instead of destroying/recreating it.

Comment: Actually that seems much slower. I just tried it out.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/G6NV8/7/

Comment: @Shmiddty Compare that to this: http://jsfiddle.net/G6NV8/8/. This one is just native Canvas. It's unbelievably faster. I think I'm going to stop using Kinetic...

Comment: @BlackSheep well yeah. The whole draw to Kinetic is being able to handle individual shapes as separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

yes.  You would do something like this:

```
$('#container').on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  shape.setScale(someValue);
  layer.batchDraw();
});
```

In other words, attach a mousemove listener to the container div element (the one you pass into the Kinetic stage).  set the shape scale with the setScale() method.  Use batchDraw() instead of draw() so that the draw operation hooks into the KineticJS animation engine for much better performance.  Otherwise, if you use draw(), you'll be redrawing the entire layer each time a mousemove event is detected, which could be hundreds of thousands of times per second depending on the browser